# Compare pixel values to replace values

Tags: python, image, numpy

[image: has eyes, noses and mouth]
[image: only overall face shape]

I have two segmentation mask. One has only an overall face shape, has no eyes, nose, and mouth,(above - I will call this A from now on.) and one has eyes, nose, and mouth.(below - B)

So, I'm trying to give the B's information about the eyes, nose, and mouth to A.  However, I want to keep the hair information when the A hair is located at the location of the former eyes, nose, and mouth.

I am trying to transfer the information of o_mask to g_mask. At this time, transfer means to change the pixel value of 1 (skin) in A into values ​​corresponding to eyes, nose, and mouth. 2 is the nose and 13 is the hair.
So I wrote the code like this:

```
np.where(B[A == 2] != 13, 2, B[A ==2])
```

But it didn't work the way I was hoping. Nothing has changed, and there is still no eye, nose, or mouth. Does anyone know the efficient code to handle this?

Comment: try this `np.where(g_mask[np.bitwise_and(o_mask == 2, g_mask  != 13)], 2, g_mask)`

Comment: @sai The following error occurs. ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1477,) () (256,256) I've tried to execute a similar code, but if you put that condition on np.where returns a one-dimensional array.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. If I am correct this time, this should be what you need `np.where(np.bitwise_and(o_mask == 2, g_mask  != 13), 2, g_mask)`

Comment: @sai Wow, it works very well. Thanks.

Comment: @sai Can I ask one more question? Only '2' was presented when asking questions, but there are a few more numbers to be checked in the same way. I think it's strange to use the for statement simply because I can't add results, is there a way to change the conditional statement of np.where? I want to do the same thing over and over again for the following number. : [2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,16]

Comment: It is better if you update your question with the details and is there any chance that you made a mistake with the words "former" and "later" in the question as of now? Cause I couldn't quite wrap my head around it

Comment: @sai The question was modified a little more. I am not sure how to express this task in English and technically. I'm sorry. As I mentioned above, I want to do the same thing over and over again for [2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,16] . The result should be one picture of B's ​​photo plus A's features.

Comment: ```contains = [2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,16]
np.where(np.bitwise_and(any(c in o_mask for c in contains) , g_mask != 13), o_mask, g_mask)``` I solved like this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure numpy solution would however be as follows-

```py
contains = [2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,16]
np.where(np.bitwise_and(np.isin(o_mask, contains), g_mask != 13), o_mask, g_mask)
```

I cannot say for sure but there can be a significant time improvement I believe with this approach/